# JTable Headlines between rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, cell, rows

I am wondering how I can realize something like this:

> ---
>
> row 1
>
> ---
>
> row 2
>
> ---
>
> *HEADLINE* like 27.01.2011
>
> ---
>
> row 3
>
> ---
>
> row 4
>
> ---
>
> *HEADLINE* like 28.01.2011
>
> ---
>
> row 5
>
> ---

These "fake" rows should be only information-rows and not real rows.  I couldn't find something like that.

I hope you understand my problem.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: not supported in core nor any pre-fabricated table variants. As @mKorbel suggested (though not showed ;-), a tree-table-like component might be an alternative (though not exactly what you want): a two-level (below the root) treeTableModel with first level being the header and its children the "real" data

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have look at [JTreeTable](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/treetable1/), [JXTreeTable](http://swingx.java.net/) by SwingX, [OutLine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6673) by NetBeans, nice workaround by [aephyr](http://aephyr.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) and one non-free product by [JideSoft](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/grids.htm)

EDIT

[image]

Comment: hhmmm... TreeTable just doesn't look like what i am searching :( I have a table, say of 10000 rows, sorted by Date. The only thing i want is to highlight a new Day in my table with a little "headline" between the rows...

Comment: +1 for a comprehensive list of tree-oriented views. Does the image show [`RowNumberTable`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/)?

Comment: The RowHeader is ok, but not exactly what i want. I "just" want a headline ABOVE a row. With the RowHeader there is alot of needed extra space and "overhead".

Comment: a tree-table-like component might indeed be the nearest off the shelf component to get - but (cough) your screenshot doesn't get very near to the original requirement

Comment: @kleopatra I think that s/he has only some problem with different Class types in one Column :-)

Comment: could well be, but if so - why do you throw treeTables and row headers into the ring? That would be random clutter in relation to the problem as you see it ;-)