# How to create a JTable like header, and use it as JTexPane header?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextpane, jtableheader

I need a JTextPane which has a header on top just like the one in a JTable. Basically I need a one row/column multiline JTable without having to go through all trouble crating renderes and editors. I tried adding a JLabel and JTextpane in a JPanel, but JLabel just isn't the same as a JTable Header and there is a gap between them.

Comment: Subclassing a JLabel and reducing its preferredSize?

Comment: @JanDvorak The visual styles aren't the same. I need it to look exactly like JTableHeader.

Comment: *"I need a JTextPane which has a header on top just like the one i a JTable."*  ..Why?

Comment: Creating a stand-alone [JTableHeader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/JTableHeader.html)?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Well, that's in the requirements, a text area which has a table like header. Raised JLabel just doesn't look good.

Comment: @Igor don't they mean functionally, not stylistically?

Comment: @JanDvorak No, renaming the header text is the only functionality needed. Creating a JTableHeader and placing it where? It just doesn't show when you add it to a JPanel. It can probably be added to a JTable only.

Answer (score 1):

- not sure if is there big troubles for JTable, sure there could be only the issues with corners
- put JPanel with JTextComponent(in JScrollPane) to the CENTER area, put JLabel/JTextField to the NORTH

  ---

  [for JLabel/JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10299581/714968)
- change Opacity
- get Color from JTableHeader (UIManager)
- put there Borders

Comment: Well there is big troubles, because text needs to bestyled, and support hyperlink, and rendering styled text from the editor in a cell, is a big trouble. Thanks for your answer I think I'll give it a try.

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work:
 - `JLabel header = new JLabel("Title");`
 - `header.setOpaque(true);`
 - `header.setBackground(UIManager.getColor(new JTableHeader()));`

Comment: Just checked - `UIManager` returns null for the color.